# Menu items and item ID

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, articles, menu-item, gantry

I've set up a site using a RocketTheme template. On the homepage there are several blog items (articles of the blog category). The homepage item ID is 110.

I also have a `blog` menu item (articles-> category: blog) in the main menu. Its item ID is 180.

In the site there's also a blog module that pull articles of the blog category.

The problem is that no matter where I click a blog item link, in the homepage, the module or the actual blog menu item, it opens the blog article in item ID 110, which is the homepage.

Most tutorials and answers say that the way around this is to create a specific menu item for the category-- but I've done this and still have the issue.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What module is this? There is no default "mod_blog" and first guess is its not using `JRoute` correctly, so we will need to know the exact module to look deeper.

Comment: Another way can be to move your article to the Category Description and then make the page for the category as Menu Item

Comment: I'm not using mod_blog, it's the normal Articles - Category module, pulling the Blog category.

Comment: To clarify: your home page is using the module articles - category to display blog posts, and you also have a menu item for category blog? - if so, what happens to your item id if you unpublish your module and simply go to the articles via the menu category-blog page?

Comment: If you are getting the itemID of the homepage, you are on the homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this helps answer the question. The reason your getting the 110 instead of the 180 Itemdid is because your on the home page. Most modules will pick up on the current Itemid (in this case the home page, 110), not the Itemdid of the target menu  your looking for. Articles aren't tied to Itemdid's when they are created. The Itemid id us purely a numerical value for a menu itemid.

Some blog modules allow you to set a target Itemid, which would tie it to the proper menu Itemid.

The only reason I can think of that your Itemdid's are being tied to 110 no matter what (even if your on the Blog menu link with 180) is that your using an external link to land on the blog page, which is carrying the 110 itemid with it?

Answer (score 0):

To get around this you have to create a "Single article" menu item. This can be in a hidden menu, and does not need to be visible to users. The layout of this menu item will then be used to display the articles. Simply make sure any modules you DON'T want to display with your article are unpublished for this particular menu item.